# How to monitor if Azure WebApp is responding?

Tags: azure-webapps, azure-monitor

I would like to build monitoring solution which monitors if WebApp is up and running and responding.

Is Application Insight metrics suffient?
What are best metrics?
How to build alert if WebApp is down?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Azure Monitor to [configure alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-overview) using Application Insights if you need more configuration options.**

As we know 5XX HTTP Error Status Codes are related to server errors and particularly 503 is site is overloaded or down for maintenance.

1. To create alert for your web app service, go to your web app service in the Azure portal
2. **Monitoring** Section > Click on **Alerts** > Create on **New Alert**
   [image]

Select Your Time range, Threshold limit etc and click on done.

[image]

Please find more information on every option while creating the alerts, logs and metrics on the above MS-DOC.